# Using the discriminants of conic sections

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

According to [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/conics-discriminant/) page , we can understand the shape of conic sections using the discriminants of general equation but how we can prove it ?  I'm really confused about that complicated formulas without any proof .

Answer (score 3):

For variety, we can prove this with the geometry of the complex projective plane.

Nondegenerate conics given by quadratic equations with real coefficients can be distinguished by how they intersect the line at infinity. There are two points of intersection with multiplicity, and they can be of the following types:

- A hyperbola meets the line at infinity in two real points, corresponding to the two asymptotes.
- A parabola is tangent to the line at infinity, and so intersects the line at infinity at a single point with multiplicity 2
- An ellipse doesn't meet the line at infinity over the reals; the intersection consists of a complex conjugate pair of points. (An ellipse has asymptotes with *complex* slope)

If we take the equation for the general quadratic and *homogenize* it, we have the equation

$$ Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dxz+Eyz+Fz^2=0$$

The line at infinity is given by the equation $z=0$. Substituting into the equation gives

$$ Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2 = 0$$

Solving this quadratic equation, we get:

- Two real solutions when the discriminant is positive — thus hyperbola
- A double solution when the discriminant is zero — thus parabola
- Two complex solutions when the discriminant is negative — thus ellipse

Comment: Thanks but I'm not familiar with complex projective plane . Can you explain about it ?

Comment: What do you mean by homogenize?

Answer (score 1):

If we have a general equation $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$, and $B\neq 0$ we rotate by $\theta$ given by $\tan{2\theta}=\frac{B}{A-C}$to eliminate this $xy$-term: the discriminant $B^2-4AC$ is invariant as we can check directly by identifying new $A',B',C',D',E',F'$ through the transformation calculate $B'^2-4A'C'$.

Now for a conic with $B=0$ we have a parabola if $A=0$ or $C=0$, i.e. $AC=0$ or they are both non-zero and we have an ellipse or circle if $A$ and $C$ have the same sign i.e. $AC>0$, and finally we have a hyperbola if they have the opposite sign i.e. $AC<0$.

Transforming to an equation with $B'=0$ through rotation, we can see that

$$B^2-4AC=B'^2-4A'C'=-4A'C'$$ since we rotate to a situation where $B'=0$. Now we can read off the criteria:

parabola: $B^2-4AC=0$

ellipse or circle: $B^2-4AC<0$

hyperbola: $B^2-4AC>0$.

Comment: What about degenerate conic section ? How we can prove that ?

Comment: @S.H.W: The rank of the symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix of coefficients is $1$ if we have a double line ($x^2=0$), $2$ if we have two lines and then the negative of the minor of the $(3,3)$-term is what's in your link. If this minor is $=0$ (while the rank is $2$) we have parallel lines, essentially $x^2=constant$. If the minor is $>0$ we can bring the equation to $x^2-y^2=0$ (the constant term can't be other than zero since then the matrix would have had rank 3) and if the minor is $<0$ we have similarly $x^2+y^2=0$. This last degenerate ellipse is the point where two imaginary lines cross.